# Python Xpath on 2 elements with the same text within them

Tags: python, html, xpath

```
<span style="">Medication Profile</span>

<span style="color:gray;">Medication Profile</span>
```

There are these 2 medication profiles and both of these could appear on a page. Now normally I would just use:

```
medProf = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Medication Profile")
```

but doing that doesn't click the medication profile thats colored grey.

I was trying this on xpath:

```
//span[@style=""color:gray;" and contains("Medication Profile")
```

but it's the wrong path.

My question is despite having both medication profiles on the same page:

```
<span style="">Medication Profile</span>

<span style="color:gray;">Medication Profile</span>
```

How do I make sure I click the gray one? and by gray one I mean this one:

```
<span style="color:gray;">Medication Profile</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) to check that there is `gray` inside `style` attribute value:

```
//span[contains(@style, "gray") and . = "Medication Profile"]
```

where `.` refers to the current node's text.

Comment: hey its you again! thank you very much. I checked it on xpath in firebug and it worked.

Is there a newbie friendly place where I can learn xpath? cause I know a little bit but not enough

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez firebug and browser developer tools are good places to practice your XPath and locating skills in general. There are multiple xpath tutorials out there on the internet, just google them. Glad to help.